# Visual Studio unable to download installation files

Tags: visual-studio

I simply wish to install Visual Studio 2017 to compile a project.

Trying to install via the installer obtained from Microsoft fails after being unable to obtain the .opc file from aka.ms (found that after checking logs in %Temp%)

Moved to a full install version with all files and .opc file present. Installer still attempts to download from the web. Fails saying it is unable to download.

Tried running installed with --layout pointing toward the location of the offline files, same error.

Installed certificates from the certificates folder both in Personal and Trusted Root stores, no difference.

Tried starting CNG Key Isolation service, fails with error 1053

Microsoft support transferred me three times before saying the problem is on their end, so how, if one were to have no internet connection and evidently has all files required for install available, install this, if the installer stubbornly attempts to download from the web?

Is there a KB I am missing or some procedure I have to follow with the full installers?

Comment: Why don't you try: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

Comment: I tried that, as I said, it seems to completely ignore the --layout parameter, no folder is created and no files are put in the specified location. The instructions state to use their installer to download the files into the cache, but that fails as it is unable to download the installer.opc file from aka.ms

Comment: I do believe the issue is related to the CNG Key Isolation Service not working, this is in one of the installer log things out of Temp:

Caught Exception: Type = CryptographicException, Message = An internal error occurred.
, StackTrace =    at System.Security.Cryptography.NCryptNative.OpenStorageProvider(String providerName)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Import(Byte[]

However I do not actually know why that service fails to start either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears the cause for this was the service disclosure debug, disabling the debug, binding all services back into the svchost and after rebooting the service is working again. I have been able to install VS now.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it is the network firewall blocking the downloading because the downloading involve not only main Microsoft visual studio site which is allowed in our network but also some url like https://aka.ms which is blocked by our firewall.the error is listed in c:\users\myusername\appdata\local\temp\dd_bootstrapper_xxx.log

Answer (score 0):

It appears from what you have submitted you are attempting to download a offline copy of Visual Studio. It also appears that you are attempting to run the file originally downloaded to create the bootstrapper for the installation.

You want to instead launch the setup executable which is actually in the layout folder.

Hope this helps. ^^

Comment: I have that setup executable, but it too creates a bootstrapper downloading files and then errors stating it was unable to download files.